# How to populate items in a DropdownButtonFormField in Flutter with data in Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use data on firebase Firestore to populate items in a DropDownFormField.
I have created this array in firestore to save this data

[image: Firestore data]

In here I want to show **deitaryItems** in the dropdown list.

I have tried this by using the below code

```
CommonDropDownField(
  items: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return data["attributesArray"];
  }).toList().cast<String>(),
  label: "Select Dietary Attribute",
  onChanged: print,
  width: 0.32,
  height: 0.05,
  focusNode: _dietaryFocus,
  hint: 'Select Dietary Attribute',
  validator: null,
),
```

CommonDropDownField is a custom DropdownButtonFormField() . But this gives an error:

> Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Comment: Can you please provide the error logs you are facing?

Comment: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this:

```
items: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return data["attributesArray"];
}).toList().cast<String>(),
```

You're trying to extract `attributesArray` from the fields of the document data, but in the screenshot you're showing `attributesArray` is actually a document itself - one that contains only a `dieteraryItems` array field.

So you either should be extracting the `dieteraryItems` field, or you'll need to load the correct document.